# VBA Print loop not writing whole loop to batch file

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

So I have an issue printing items to a batch file.  I have a bunch of cells which have the names, start dates, and end dates for tasks that are in task scheduler.  I am trying to loop through these cells and write the corresponding lines of code needed to change the task scheduler.

When I run the code, it only prints part of the loop into the batch file.  I have had some success when I step through the code line by line where the entire loop will write.

```
'loop through list creating command line for .bat
Dim i As Integer
For i = 8 To finalRow

commandLine = "ECHO hunter2| Schtasks /Change /TN """
'Scan name and concatonate
commandFragment = Cells(i, "B").Value
commandLine = commandLine & commandFragment
commandLine = commandLine & """ /SD "

'scan start date and concatonate
day = Cells(i, "E").Value
commandFragment = DayRefs(translateDay(day))
commandLine = commandLine & commandFragment
commandLine = commandLine & " /ST "

'scan start time and concatonate
commandFragment = Cells(i, "G").Value
commandLine = commandLine & commandFragment
commandLine = commandLine & " /ED "

'scan end date and concatonate
day = Cells(i, "F").Value
commandFragment = DayRefs(translateDay(day))
commandLine = commandLine & commandFragment
commandLine = commandLine & " /RI 1440"

'save completed command line to Commands
Commands(i - 6) = commandLine

Next

'open .bat for modification
Dim fnum As Variant
fnum = FreeFile()
Open AutomationFile For Output As #fnum

Print #fnum, "@ECHO"

'print commands
For i = 1 To finalRow - 6
Print #fnum, Commands(i)
Print #fnum, " "
Next
```

This is a copy of what is currently spitting out in the batch file.  It is just stopping mid row.  And the current iteration of this should have 8 separate items but its only getting through 4 and part of number 5.

> ```
> @ECHO
>
> ECHO hunter2| Schtasks /Change /TN "Report Update Morning" /SD
> 07/22/2020 /ST 07:55 /ED 07/31/2020 /RI 1440
>
> ECHO hunter2| Schtasks /Change /TN "Report Update Lunch" /SD
> 07/22/2020 /ST 11:55 /ED 07/31/2020 /RI 1440
>
> ECHO hunter2| Schtasks /Change /TN "Report Update Evening" /SD
> 07/22/2020 /ST 17:25 /ED 07/31/2020 /RI 1440
>
> ECHO hunter2| Schtasks /Change /TN "AA Sweep Macro Morning" /SD
> 07/27/2020 /ST 08:00 /ED 07/31/2020 /RI 1440
>
> ECHO hunter2| Schtasks /Change /TN "A
> ```

Comment: It looks like you should be changing things at line `12` because you're not joining the translated day to the same line, as you have with all of the others, i.e. this should be one line `ECHO hunter2| Schtasks /Change /TN "Report Update Morning" /SD 07/22/2020 /ST 07:55 /ED 07/31/2020 /RI 1440`, not two! If it is actually outputting as one line and not two, then you didn't format your content correctly, and should do so now to prevent further confusion.

Comment: As for your issue, I'm not sure if you're expecting us to guess the content of the cell value, but for all we know it's a character in that cell giving you the issue. We really need more information.

Comment: @Compo all of the cells are set up in a similar fashion.  The next line is AA Sweep Macro Lunch.  All of the names are alpha characters with only spaces.  It doesn't appear to be a data issue because if I step through the code everything writes correctly.  However if I run the code it gets partway through and then cuts off mid line.

Comment: Does the same thing occur, when you change your vb code from `For i = 8 To finalRow` to `For i = 13 To finalRow`, i.e does it fail similarly after the same number of lines? If so, it may be that your concatenation, or buffer is being filled with too much information before it is asked to print it to the bat file.